# AngularJs: Directive calls services method

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post, angularjs-directive

I have a directive and in the .js file I call, under controller, the service method in this way:

```
controller: ['$scope', 'cartItems', function ($scope, cartItems) {
 $scope.startDownload = function () {
            setInitialState();      
            cartItems.removeAllItem();                                                          
            $scope.$emit("ON_DOWNLOAD_START","updated");
        }
```

In my service i have this method :

```
removeAllItem: function(){
            var getCartUrl = "URL";
             $http({
                 url: getCartUrl,              
                 method: "POST"           
             }).success(function(){
             }).error(function(err){
                 console.error('Error: %s error: %O', 'removeAllItem[*] failed.', err);
             });
        }
```

In my php method, I just call this :`unset ($_SESSION['Cart'])`

It works but the service prints in the console the error messagge :                     `"Error: %s error: %O', 'removeAllItem[*] failed"` . (This message is in the service method `removeAllItem`)

Comment: try `var getCartUrl = "/";`

Comment: ???? in the var getCartUrl, I assigned the real url

Comment: 1) Does the `function(err)` err var contain anything ? 
2) What is the http status returned by the POST ? (you can either see in the dev tools or add a `status` var as `function(err, status)` )